# Add Esp32-Wifi library to PlatformIO

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, wifi, esp32, platformio

Hello i can't find out how i can add the Esp32 Wifi Library (https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WiFi) to my PlatformIO Project (VS-Code). How am I able to add and import it?
I tried to copy it into the libs folder, and add the link to lib_deps

And Stackoverflow just says this Problem is not described good enough... Sorry for the lines at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly add the Wifi library. It's part of the ESP32 Arduino Core support.

You do need a correctly written `platformio.ini` file for that to work. That file would look something like this:

```
[env: esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
framework = arduino
board = esp32dev
lib_deps = ...
```

Where you would replace `esp32dev` with the correct name for the board you're using.

If you don't have `framework` set to `arduino`, PlatformIO won't load the Arduino Core and you won't have the wifi library available.

Comment: I know WiFi is Preinstalled, but its a version that doesnt detect my shield and doesnt support the mode() function. I want to install just that specific library from the link

Comment: The specific version from that link is already installed if you've set your framework to Arduino. If it's not working with your hardware then you have a different problem.